# Django loaddata error

Tags: python, django

I created a "fixtures" folder in the app directory and put data1.json in there.

This is what is in the file:

```
[{"firm_url": "http://www.graychase.com/kadam", "firm_name": "Gray & Chase", "first": " Karin ", "last": "Adam", "school": "Ernst Moritz Arndt University Greifswald",  "year_graduated": " 2004"} ]
```

In the command line I cd to the app directory and

```
django-admin.py loaddata data1.json
```

but I get this error

```
Installing json fixture 'data1' from
'C:\Users\A\Documents\Projects\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures'.
Problem installing fixture
'C:\Users\A\Documents\Projects\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures\data1.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 150, in handle for obj in objects:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 41, in Deserializer for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream)):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 76, in Deserializer
Model = _get_model(d["model"])
KeyError: 'model'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I fixed the json format:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "wkw2.Lawyer", 
        "fields": {
            "school": "The George Washington University Law School", 
            "last": "Babas", 
            "firm_url": "http://www.graychase.com/babbas", 
            "year_graduated": "2005", 
            "firm_name": "Gray & Chase", 
            "first": "Amr A"
        }
    }
]
```

But now I get ValidationError: This value must be an integer. Is there a way to find out from the line numbers what causes the error? Only "pk" is an integer.

```
Problem installing fixture 'C:\~\sw2\wkw2\fixtures\csvtest1.csv.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 150, in handle for obj in objects:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 41, in  Deserializer for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream)):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 95, in Deserializer data[field.attname] =  field.rel.to._meta.get_field(field.rel.field_name).to_python(field_value)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 356, in to_python_("This value must be an integer."))

ValidationError: This value must be an integer.
```

Comment: Can you please post data1.json as well?

Comment: Hint: use the --indent option to dumpdata to make it more readable.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#djadminopt---indent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it looks like you are not defining your fixtures properly.  Take a look at the [Django Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#howto-initial-data).  You need to define the model that you are loading, then define the fields like this

```
 [
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed the fixture and now it looks like this but I get a ValidationError: "This value must be an integer" See my edit. I wonder if there is a way to copy and paste this data into my Sqlite3 database, since it is a file?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is within the fixture you've created. The following might cause problems:

- Changing the database schema after creating a fixture, then loading the fixture into your new schema
- Manually fiddling with the contents of the fixture.

Did you create the fixture using `manage.py dumpdata`?