# Django loaddata ValidationError

Tags: python, django, json, csv

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884827/django-loaddata-error) got too confusing (for me) so I am asking the question again. I could not make the csv2json.py script mentioned in the original question work. I am just trying to find a way to import data to sqlite3 database.

Here's the model I am working with:

```
from django.db import models

class School(models.Model):    
    school = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.school

class Lawyer(models.Model):
    firm_url = models.URLField('Bio', max_length=200)
    firm_name = models.CharField('Firm', max_length=100)
    first = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=50)
    last = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=50)
    year_graduated = models.IntegerField('Year graduated')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('?',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first
```

(I'll fix the duplicate "school" later.)

I have this data1.csv file:

```
pk,firm_url,firm_name,first,last,school,year_graduated
1,http://www.graychase.com/babbas, Gray & Chase, Amr A, Babbas, The George Washington University Law School, 2005
```

I have to put in "pk" and 1 manually as required by the script.

Then, I run the script and I get the data1.csv.json file:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "wkw2.Lawyer", 
        "fields": {
            "school": "The George Washington University Law School", 
            "last": "Babbas", 
            "firm_url": "http://www.graychase.com/babbas", 
            "year_graduated": "2005", 
            "firm_name": "Gray & Chase", 
            "first": "Amr A"
        }
    }
]
```

I put this file in the fixtures folder in the app directory and run `manage.py loaddata data1.csv.json`

and I get the error

```
Installing json fixture 'data1.csv' from 'C:\~\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures'.

Problem installing fixture 'C:\~\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures\data1.csv.json': Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 150, in handle for obj in objects:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 41, in Deserializer for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream)):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 95, in Deserializer data[field.attname] = field.rel.to._meta.get_fie(field.rel.field_name).to_python(field_value)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 356, in to_python_("This value must be an integer."))
ValidationError: This value must be an integer.
```

When I comment out the two lines in the script with pk in them I get this error message:

```
Installing json fixture 'data1.csv' from 'C:\~\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures'.
Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\A\Documents\Projects\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures\data1.csv.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 150, in handle for obj in objects:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 41, in Deserializer for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream)):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 77, in Deserializer data = {Model._meta.pk.attname : Model._meta.pk.to_pytho(["pk"])} 

KeyError: 'pk'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I took out the quotes around the year to make it an integer but I still got the same ValidationError:

```
...
            "year_graduated": 2005, 
...
```

Comment: FWIW, I consider this to be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884827/django-loaddata-error

Comment: School must be integer (a pk for existing School object) according to your model definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (I'll fix the duplicate "school" later.)

Actually, that is your problem. The second definition of school as a foreign key will require it to be an integer, thus the error.

You can confirm this by dumping the schema of your table with

> sqlite3 *<database-file>* '.schema wkw2_Lawyer'